# Computing the DFT according to the definition (C++ with <complex>)

Tags: c++, dft

I'm trying to implement the "Naive" definition of the Discrete Fourier Transform using nothing but C++ and its standard libs, for my own personal understanding of the mathematical material, and I keep getting incorrect output, despite my code seeming to be a direct translation of the mathematical definition of the DFT.

Here's the code (edited so as to clean up the output better than the original):

```
void DFT(std::complex<double>* outputs, int N, std::complex<double>* inputs)
{
  for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k) 
  {
    outputs[k] = std::complex<double>(0.0, 0.0);
    for (int t = 0; t < N; ++t) 
    {
       // tk2π/N
       double angle = t * k * TWOPI / double(N);
       // e^(-jtk2π/N)
       std::complex<double> dft_sino = std::polar(1.0, -angle);

      if(fabs(real(dft_sino)) < std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon())
        dft_sino = std::complex<double>(0.0, imag(dft_sino));

      if(fabs(imag(dft_sino)) < std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon())
        dft_sino = std::complex<double>(real(dft_sino), 0.0);

      std::cout << "DFT sinosoid (" << k << "), Sample " << t << ": " << dft_sino << std::endl;
      outputs[k] += inputs[t] * dft_sino;
    }
  }
}
```

The input set is:

```
 1+1i
-1+1i
 1-1i
-1-1i
-3-1i
 4-2i
 0-3i
 2-6i
```

The (verified) output I expect is:

```
 3-12i
 10.24+5.243i
 3+2i
 9.071+10.07i
-5+4i
 1.757-3.243i
-9+6i
-5.071-4.071i
```

And the output of the program in its current form is:

```
 3+2i
 3.293+6.364i
-2-1i
 6.121+6.95i
-5-4.91e-15i
 4.707-6.364i
-4+3i
 1.879-2.95i
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Edit: below is the output of samples for the corresponding DFT sinusoid samples which are multiplied by the input during the summation.

```
DFT sinusoid (0):
Sample 0: 1+0i
Sample 1: 1+0i
Sample 2: 1+0i
Sample 3: 1+0i
Sample 4: 1+0i
Sample 5: 1+0i
Sample 6: 1+0i
Sample 7: 1+0i

DFT sinusoid (1):
Sample 0: 1+0i
Sample 1: 0.7071-0.7071i
Sample 2: 0-1i
Sample 3: -0.7071-0.7071i
Sample 4: -1+0i
Sample 5: -0.7071+0.7071i
Sample 6: 0+1i
Sample 7: 0.7071+0.7071i

DFT sinusoid (2):
Sample 0: 1+0i
Sample 1: 0-1i
Sample 2: -1+0i
Sample 3: 0+1i
Sample 4: 1+0i
Sample 5: 0-1i
Sample 6: -1+0i
Sample 7: 0+1i

DFT sinusoid (3):
Sample 0: 1+0i
Sample 1: -0.7071-0.7071i
Sample 2: 0+1i
Sample 3: 0.7071-0.7071i
Sample 4: -1+0i
Sample 5: 0.7071+0.7071i
Sample 6: 0-1i
Sample 7: -0.7071+0.7071i

DFT sinusoid (4):
Sample 0: 1+0i
Sample 1: -1+0i
Sample 2: 1+0i
Sample 3: -1+0i
Sample 4: 1+0i
Sample 5: -1+0i
Sample 6: 1+0i
Sample 7: -1+0i

DFT sinusoid (5):
Sample 0: 1+0i
Sample 1: -0.7071+0.7071i
Sample 2: 0-1i
Sample 3: 0.7071+0.7071i
Sample 4: -1+0i
Sample 5: 0.7071-0.7071i
Sample 6: 0+1i
Sample 7: -0.7071-0.7071i

DFT sinusoid (6):
Sample 0: 1+0i
Sample 1: 0+1i
Sample 2: -1+0i
Sample 3: 0-1i
Sample 4: 1+0i
Sample 5: 0+1i
Sample 6: -1+0i
Sample 7: 0-1i

DFT sinusoid (7):
Sample 0: 1+0i
Sample 1: 0.7071+0.7071i
Sample 2: 0+1i
Sample 3: -0.7071+0.7071i
Sample 4: -1+0i
Sample 5: -0.7071-0.7071i
Sample 6: 0-1i
Sample 7: 0.7071-0.7071i
```

Comment: As even your zero-frequency output term is wrong, this ought to be easy to debug.  The zero-frequency term is literally just the sum of the input terms, so you should be able to step through line-by-line to see where the behaviour goes wrong.

Comment: I've tried stepping through it a few times. Unfortunately I'm not experienced enough with this math to know what would be considered unusual or wrong behavior. What should I be looking for?

Comment: You could break the complex math expression into a series of separate statements, storing intermediate results into local variables, and check these one by one.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, how is `TWOPI` defined here?

Comment: TWOPI is defined as 2.0*PI, and PI is defined as 4.0*atan(1.0)

Comment: I've also just added the DFT sinusoids' samples, according to how I'm calculating them in the program, to the main post. It seems a little odd that sample 0 in each is just 1. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Looking further at the [matrix formulation of the dft](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/st/Matrix_Formulation_DFT.html), it looks like those 1s are correct. I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I just cleaned up my dft sinusoids and compared their values to the [wiki's 8x8 matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) and I'm reasonably certain they're correct now. Still getting incorrect output, but now I know it's not in the sinusoid values.

Comment: Finally figured it out thanks to Frank's initial suggestion about the zero-frequency term. Turns out my dft function was/is correct, it's just that the data I was reading in was in an incorrect format (which I had edited away for readability on here). Thanks Frank!

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that there is nothing wrong with your implementation of `DFT`, and I was able to confirm that with the proper input, the function produces the output you expect. What this means though is that there is an issue with the input it receives. Implementing the inverse transform in a similar fashion suggests that the following input was actually fed to the `DFT` function:

```
 1+1i
-1+1i
 1+0i
-1+0i
-3+0i
 4+0i
 0+0i
 2+0i
```

From this it looks like you are missing the imaginary part of most inputs (apart from `inputs[0]` and `inputs[1]`). Since you did not provide how the data in `inputs` is generated and passed to `DFT` it is impossible to tell exactly why that is. However, here are a number of common causes that may lead to such an issue, which you may use as starting points while investigating why the `inputs` to the function isn't what you thought it was:

- Accidentally (or not) overwriting the input buffer imaginary parts with zeros. This could in turn be due to:

  - Providing the same array for the `inputs` and `outputs` arguments to `DFT` (this implementation requires them to be distinct arrays);
  - Using input and output arrays which are smaller than the transform size `N` and subsequently writing out-of-bounds while writing values to those arrays;
- Actually forgetting to set the imaginary parts;
- Incorrectly getting real/imaginary parts while reading them from file, or other parts of the program (e.g. assuming a file contains 8 real parts followed by 8 imaginary part when the file actually contains only 10 values).